# Azure notification hub: Send notification - Getting the impacted users

Tags: java, azure-notificationhub

I'm using [azure-notificationhubs-java-backend](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-java-backend) to send notifications to Azure hub. I have Azure tags created per application user. Business require me to send notification to multiple users (this part is achieved), and report back the execution status, i.e. whom Azure was able to deliver the notification, and who all were missed (so that other communication can be made with those users). We've this scenario that not all users are yet registered with Azure. Below is the call I am making:

```
SyncCallback<NotificationOutcome> callback = new SyncCallback<>();
notificationHub.sendNotificationAsync(templateNotification, recipientTags, callback);
NotificationOutcome outcome = callback.getResult();
// outcome has just the notificationId, and trackingId
```

Any suggestion how can I get success and failed tags. Or there's some other call I can make using the `notificationId` or `trackingId` to meet the desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get this data from per message telemetry. Please see below blog for more information.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/retrieve-platform-notification-system-error-details-with-azure-notification-hubs/